# How to parse html table data to array of string in swift?

Tags: web-scraping, html-parsing, swift4, swiftsoup

I'm developing an iOS app in which I need to parse HTML from a link with the swiftsoup library. I have done it. But it shows all the table data as a string. I need to get separate data which should be stored in separate arrays.

Here is the table:

```
        <table width="880" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
      <tr>
        <td width="81"><strong>Trip Name </strong></td>
        <td width="159"><div align="center"><strong>Starting Time from Campus </strong></div></td>
        <td width="186"><div align="center"><strong>Starting Spot &amp; Time </strong></div></td>
        <td width="444"><strong>Remarks</strong></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><div align="center">Normal-1</div></td>
        <td><div align="center">6:30 AM </div></td>
        <td>Rupsha, 7:20 AM </td>
        <td>Will back via Royalmore &amp; Ferighat  </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><div align="center">Normal-1</div></td>
        <td><div align="center">6:45 AM </div></td>
        <td>Moylapota, 7:25 AM </td>
        <td>Will back via Shibbari - Sonadangha </td>
      </tr>


    </table>
```

And I have done to parse a string like
Trip Name Starting Time from Campus Starting Spot & Time Remarks Normal-1

The code I've used :

```
let doc: Document = try! SwiftSoup.parse(html)

for element: Element in try! doc.select("table[width=880]")
{
    let linkText : String = try! element.text();
    print(linkText)
}
```

The Normal-1, 6:30AM, 7:20AM , Will back via Royalmore & Ferighat will be stored 4 separate array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure whether you want to store it as one-array-per-row or one-array-per-column. Here's how you can store it in one-array-per-row style. Use `map` or other array transformations to convert it ot the style you want:

```
var tableContent = [[String]]()
let document = try! SwiftSoup.parse(html)
for row in try! document.select("table[width=\"880\"] tr") {
    var rowContent = [String]()

    for col in try! row.select("td") {
        let colContent = try! col.text()
        rowContent.append(colContent)
    }
    tableContent.append(rowContent)
}

print(tableContent)
```

(If you do this in production, handle errors properly instead of all those `try!`)